# Breaking down progress(Percentage) through each quarter of the year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, percentage, datepart

Basically I am trying to calculate the progress of the current quarter, represented as a percentage.  Currently I have:

```
(DATEPART(dd,@AsOf)/91) * 100
```

We are using 91 days as a fixed solution for the quarter.  They necessity for 100% accuracy is not required.

`@AsOf` is being passed in as a `DATETIME` type.

I have tried multiple ways and I receive 0.  I assume it is because I am using `INT` instead of `DECIMAL` but I tried that and I still get 0.

Comment: datepart with "dd" will give you the day of the month, i assume you don't want that?!

Comment: I do want the day of the month.  Basically the idea is...EXAMPLE fiscal Quarter 10/1/20** - 12/31/20**. "10/23/20**, take the 23 and divide by 91. If "11/19/20**, 31(days in Oct) + 19(date in Nov) = 50/91.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to force it to be a decimal by adding a decimal point, like `91.0` and `100.0` to avoid [integer division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) issues:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME 
set @date = getdate();

select DATEPART(dd,@date) TheDay,
      (DATEPART(dd,@date)/91.0) DivBy91,
      (DATEPART(dd,@date)/91.0) * 100.0 Result
```

Result:

```
TheDay  DivBy91  Result
19      0.208791 20,8791000
```

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

What integer division will do is produce `0` in column 2, which is what is causing your result to be 0.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was over thinking that process.  I tried using CONVERT because I was receiving errors.  Didn't occur to me to just apply ".0"  to the end of the divisor and multiplier.